# What this sequence '[[A-Z][a-z]]' means in regular expression in python?

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to search some patterns in regular expression in python.

As we know if we use the pattern, **'[A-Za-z]+'** , it means find the sequence of  characters which either contains uppercase A to Z or lowercase a to z.
So my single line of code (followed by answer) was,

```
>>> re.findall('[A-Za-z]+', 'This is my area!')
['This', 'is', 'my', 'area']
```

When I tried some another pattern **'[[A-Z][a-z]]+'** it returned an empty list, single line of code is as follow,

```
>>> re.findall('[[A-Z][a-z]]+', 'This is my area!')
[]
```

So, when I use two sequence inside a character set, what pattern is getting created ?
Please guide.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the second pattern?

Comment: @C-Otto  I was just experimenting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The engine will treat `[[A-Z][a-z]]+` as:

- `[[A-Z]` as the first character class which allows any upper case letter (A-Z) or a `[`. Think of it as `[\[A-Z]` instead where `[` is escaped
- `[a-z]` as the second character class which will allow any lower case letter (a-z)
- `]+` allows one or more `]`

So it will match `[b]` or `Aa]` or `Aa]]]]]]]` etc. and won't match your string 'This is my area!'

To play around with it further you can try this [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/9HLin6/1).

**Nesting of Square Brackets:**

To better understand how nesting of square brackets works in regex, consider another example `[[[ABC]]]`

> Once an opening square bracket is found (`[`) which indicates the start of a character class then **all subsequent opening square brackets** `[` are treated as escaped `\[` until a closing square bracket is encountered `]` which indicates end of the character class.

To test it out, take a look at these examples:

- `[[[ABC]]]` is same as `[\[ABC]` followed by `]{2}`. Example `A]]`
- `[[[[ABC]]]]` is same as `[\[ABC]` followed by `]{3}`. Example `[]]]`
- `[[[[[ABC]]]]]` is same as `[\[ABC]` followed by `]{4}`. Example `A]]]]`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks , that regex link is really helpful !